# how can i style these 2 images inside a div?

Tags: html, css

i'm building a small website at my internship in raw html/css. I started off with an inline stylesheet but my boss told me to use a external stylesheet. And now i'm wondering how can i style the two images below that are located inside the divs (fact1 & fact2). I'm sorry if there is an easy answer but i couldn't find anything about it..

```html
<div class="text">

<div>
<h3>header 1  </h3> 

<p>Text 1 </p>



<h3>header 2 </h3> 
<p>Text 2 </p>

 <h3>header 3 </h3>
 
 <img src="img/ketor.jpg">
 
<p>Text 3 </p>

 <div class="fact1"> 


<img src="img/fact1.png">
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="fact2">
 
<img src="img/fact2.png">
 
    </div> 
 
    </div>
 
 
</div>
```

Comment: forgot to give you any css!! here it comes  this is the styling for the top image. "width:100%;margin-top:10px;" for the second there is just this "width:100%;

Answer (score 0):

Since each div has a distinct class

```
<div class="fact1"> 
<img src="img/fact1.png">
</div>

<div class="fact2"> 
<img src="img/fact2.png">
</div>
```

You can select them by selecting the image inside that classed div

e.g.

```
div.fact1 img {
your styles here
}

div.fact2 img {
your styles here
}

 and so on.
```

Note, if you have other divs with the same class, the styles will apply to images inside those dvs too.

Comment: when i used the inline styling, the two images would stay in the big div. Now when i'm using the external css both images override the div they are supposed to be in how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a css file and place it in the same directory as your html file.

```
folder/index.html
folder/main.css
```

**main.css**

```
.fact1 img 
{
  width:100%;margin-top:10px;
}
.fact2 img 
{
  width:100%;
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>your title</title>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
<div class="text">
    <div>
        <h3>header 1</h3>
        <p>Text 1</p>
        <h3>header 2</h3>
        <p>Text 2</p>
        <h3>header 3</h3>
        <img src="img/ketor.jpg"> 
        <p>Text 3</p>
        <div class="fact1">
            <img src="img/fact1.png"> 
        </div>
        <div class="fact2">
            <img src="img/fact2.png"> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the `<head>` of your html page you want to call load that style sheet.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
```

the href attribute is the path from your html page to the style sheet. It can be a relative or absolute path.

**Relative:** Path starts from the html file and leads to the css file.

**Absolute:** Path starts from the root of the web server and leads to the file.

```
/category/index.html
/assets/css/main.css
```

For this example:

The relative path would be

```
../assets/css/main.css
```

the absolute path would be

```
/assets/css/main.css
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the images like background property of your divs so if you wanted to modify after just would have to change your css file.

```
div.fact1  {
 background:url(../img/fact1.png/) center center no-repeat;

div.fact2  {
 background:url(../img/fact2.png/) center center no-repeat;
}
```